# Error - Apache Cassandra 2.0.5 & Datastax OpsCenter 4.1

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, opscenter

I am using cassandra 2.0.5 on Centos 6.5 and OpsCenter 4 worked fine until i updated OpsCenter to version 4.1 . I access OpsCenter page, click on manage existing cluster and give the ip address of my node (127.0.0.1) and it gives me the following: "Error creating cluster: max() arg is an empty sequence".

Any clues ?

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace from the opscenter log if there is one?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/578747/opscenter-max-arg-is-an-empty-sequence stacktrace included

Answer (score 5):

The bug is on 4.1.0, and is affecting those running Python 2.6. The complete fix for this is 4.1.1 (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/opscenter-4-1-1-now-available).  To workaround this issue on 4.1.0, users should disable the auto-update feature, and manually re-populate the latest definitions. This will only need to be done once.  This doesn't need to be done with 4.1.1, and that's the best fix.  See the Known issues of the release notes (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.1/opsc/release_notes/opscReleaseNotes410.html)

1. Add the following to opscenterd.conf to disable auto-update:

> ```
> [definitions]
> auto_update = False
> ```

1. Manually download the definition files

for tarball installs:

> ```
> cd ./conf/definitions
> ```

for packages installs:

> ```
> cd /etc/opscenter/definitions
> ```

Apply the latest definitions

> ```
> curl https://opscenter.datastax.com/definitions/4.1.0/definition_files.tgz | tar xz
> ```

Restart opscenterd

Answer (score 0):

I jus had today the same problem that you. I downloaded an older versions of opscenter (particulary version 4.0.2) from http://rpm.datastax.com/community/noarch/ and the error has gone.

I am also using the sam cassandra version and also on centos